# BindToItems ErrorInternalServerTransientError on 251'st item

Tags: exchange-server, exchangewebservices

My issue is essentially the same as this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31406770/exchange-web-service-bindtoitems-method-returning-error). However, I have a temporary work-around, but would like some ideas about how to resolve the underlying issue in a simple robust manner.

I'd been calling SyncFolderItems with the maximum allowed value of 512 items.
This worked fine. However, calling BindToItems with the full collection of item IDs returned from SyncFolderItems was showing the 251'st item as having failed with ErrorInternalServerTransientError. All the other items, 0..249, and 251..511 were fine.

Examining event logs showed this from Exchange:

> Mapi session "*snipped*" exceeded the maximum of 250 objects of type "objtMessage".

It seems odd that EWS managed to get the other items OK - I'd have expected everything after 250 to have failed, but anyhow...

My immediate workaround is to substantially reduce the number of items that I ask for from SyncFolderItems. However I think that side-steps the issue since the Exchange setting is configurable, and could be set less than the value I choose.

Given that it's more efficient not to discard the whole batch of items I've got, how do you code around this scenario - given that the updated SyncState from SyncFolderItems will include the item that's failed?